# Set ansible variables based on other variable. If/else equivalent in other languages

Tags: ansible

How can I accomplish something like below in ansible?

```
if prod == true,
then var1 = 1
     var2 = 2
     var3 = 3
else
     var1 = 4
     var2 = 5
     var3 = 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use *set_fact*. For example the playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    prod: true
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        var1: 1
        var2: 2
        var3: 3
      when: prod|bool
    - set_fact:
        var1: 4
        var2: 5
        var3: 6
      when: not prod|bool
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ var1 }}-{{ var2 }}-{{ var3 }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1-2-3"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**Note**. Explicitly cast `prod|bool` in the tasks if you want to set `prod` from the command-line `--extra-vars "prod=false"`. Such variables are declared text.

Comment: I have actually tried that in my playbook. When I run it it gives a warning about a duplicate dict key, and then my variables come back as undefined.  I split the 2 set_facts out to 2 separate tasks, and when I run it like that it just skips my second task.

Comment: I've updated the answer with all the details. Please, edit the question with all the details too.

Comment: This works as you have it, but it fails when I pass it in as an extra var(which is how I was hoping to run it).  `--extra-vars "prod=false"`

Comment: Explicitly cast prod|bool in the tasks.